# XML GetText from element with attribute

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I want to `GetText` from specific element and attribute from XML using Tinyxml-2, but I cant do it.

My XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
<entry key="NAME">AAA/entry>
<entry key="SURNAME">BBB</entry>
</properties>
```

My code is:

```
  tinyxml2::XMLError eResult = xml_doc.LoadFile("C:\\test.xml");
  if (eResult != tinyxml2::XML_SUCCESS) return false;

  tinyxml2::XMLNode* root = xml_doc.FirstChildElement("properties");
  if (root == NULL) return false;

  tinyxml2::XMLElement* element = root->FirstChildElement("entry");
  if (element == NULL) return false;

  element->GetText()//return first element text "AAA"
```

How to get others text with same node name and different attribute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read all elements with needed tag. Try like this:

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement* element = root->FirstChildElement("entry");
while (element != nullptr)
{
    const char * szAttributeText = nullptr;

    szAttributeText = element->Attribute("key");
    if (szAttributeText == nullptr) return tinyxml2::XML_ERROR_PARSING_ATTRIBUTE;
    std::string strAttrKey = szAttributeText;

    // ...

    element = element->NextSiblingElement("entry");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, i can get name and surname using your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution like this,

```
  const char* name;
  const char* surname;

  tinyxml2::XMLElement* element = root->FirstChildElement("entry");
  while (element != NULL)
  {
      if(element->Attribute("key","NAME"))
      {
         name=element->GetText();
      }
      else if(element->Attribute("key","SURNAME"))
      {
         surname=element->GetText();
      }
  }
```